# What steps are involved when upgrading cakephp from version 2.2 to 2.3?

Tags: cakephp

I want to upgrade my CakePHP app from version 2.2 to 2.3, what should I do?

Is overwriting the lib folder enough? I checked the diff and noticed there are also changes in the app folder, so its not clear if these needs to be updated as well.

Migration guide has no information on how to perform the upgrade.

Comment: you should really put more effort in trying to find resources first.. the migration guide can easily be found via google

Comment: Migration guide does not have _any_ information about how to upgrade. It describes what changed and what should we pay attention.

Comment: TRY - try it and you will see. In this case you will see that it (quite expectantly of course) it will work to overwrite the lib/Cake folder and adjust the app according to the migration guide.

Comment: Actually I became uncertain if next versions will assume that I have these changes in my app folder what I saw from the diff. Any way, I successfully upgraded without any problem.

Comment: It seems to work. However my unit test cases throw notices: Notice: Undefined index: id in /lib/Cake/TestSuite/Fixture/CakeTestFixture.php on line 285

Comment: He doesn't deserve a negative. It's not entirely clear from the CakePHP site; even if it is obvious, it's better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: The [migration guide to 2.5](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-5-migration-guide.html) doesn't have any instructions about upgrading, especially not the succinct answer provided below by Oldskool.  It essentially reads like a changelog.

The same is true for 2.4 and 2.3 as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Updating the lib folder for a "minor" upgrade like this is generally enough.
A complete list of changes/checks you can run when migrating is always available in the [Migration Guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-3-migration-guide.html).